# Redux+React+Typescript - What is the proper way to save the selected index state of a navigation bar

Tags: typescript, webpack, asp.net-core, react-redux, visual-studio-2017

New to these technologies and have a question regarding my single page application.  I started with the reactredux example from this template:

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2017/02/14/building-single-page-applications-on-asp-net-core-with-javascriptservices/

The root component of my SPA is the layout.  The NavMenu is directly under the layout as well as the RightNavMenu object.  The RightNavMenu changes depending on the state of the NavMenu, so I setup the NavMenu store at the layout level as follows:

index.ts:

```
import * as NavMenu from './NavMenu';

// The top-level state object
export interface ApplicationState {       
navMenu: NavMenu.NavMenuState //-stores information on which index is currently selected
}

// Whenever an action is dispatched, Redux will update each top-level application state property using
// the reducer with the matching name. It's important that the names match exactly, and that the reducer
// acts on the corresponding ApplicationState property type.
export const reducers = {
navMenu: NavMenu.reducer
};

// This type can be used as a hint on action creators so that its 'dispatch' and 'getState' params are
// correctly typed to match your store.
export interface AppThunkAction<TAction> {
(dispatch: (action: TAction) => void, getState: () => ApplicationState): void;
}
```

Here is my NavMenu store (NavMenu.ts):
    import { Action, Reducer } from 'redux';

```
export interface NavMenuState {
selectedIndex: number;    
}

interface SelectIndexAction { type: 'NAV_SELECT_INDEX' }
interface DoNothingAction { type: 'NAV_DO_NOTHING' }

type KnownAction = SelectIndexAction | DoNothingAction;

export const actionCreators = {
select: (selectedIndex:number) => <SelectIndexAction>{ type: 'NAV_SELECT_INDEX' },
donothing: () => <DoNothingAction>{ type: 'NAV_DO_NOTHING' }
};

export const reducer: Reducer<NavMenuState> = (state: NavMenuState, action: KnownAction) => {
switch (action.type) {
    case 'NAV_SELECT_INDEX':
        alert('hasdf');
        return { selectedIndex: state.selectedIndex };        
    case 'NAV_DO_NOTHING':
        return { selectedIndex: state.selectedIndex };
    default:
        // The following line guarantees that every action in the     KnownAction union has been covered by a case above
        const exhaustiveCheck: never = action;
}

// For unrecognized actions (or in cases where actions have no effect), must return the existing state
//  (or default initial state if none was supplied)
return state || { selectedIndex: 0 };
};
```

Here is my NavMenu.tsx component:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { ApplicationState } from '../store';
import { List, ListItem, makeSelectable } from 'material-ui/List';
import * as NavMenuStore from '../store/NavMenu';

let SelectableList = makeSelectable(List);
type NavMenuProps = NavMenuStore.NavMenuState
& typeof NavMenuStore.actionCreators
& { params: { startIndex: string } };       // ... plus incoming routing      parameters


export class NavMenu extends React.Component<NavMenuProps, null> { 
componentWillMount() {

    // This method runs when the component is first added to the page
    let selectedIndex = parseInt(this.props.params.startIndex) || 0; //parse the int or set to 0 if it fails
    if (selectedIndex == 0) //if the parse fails select the first index by defaualt
        selectedIndex = 1;
    this.props.select(selectedIndex);
}  

public render() { 
    return (  
        <SelectableList defaultValue={1}>
            <p>Current index: <strong>{this.props.selectedIndex}</strong>        </p>
            <ListItem onClick={() => { this.props.select(1) }} value={1} primaryText="TestIndex1"   />              
            <ListItem onClick={() => { this.props.select(2) }} value={2} primaryText="TestIndex2"  />              
        </SelectableList>
    );
}

}

export default connect(
(state: ApplicationState) => state.navMenu, // Selects which state properties are merged into the component's props
NavMenuStore.actionCreators                 // Selects which action creators are merged into the component's props
)(NavMenu);
```

Finally, this is how I am embedding it in my layout component:

```
<NavMenu />
```

The above throws an error about missing properties, so I tried changing to this, but it still does not work.

```
<NavMenu donothing={null} params={null} selectedIndex={0} select={ null } />
```

Can someone please tell me what I am doing wrong?  I am currently just trying to output the selected index at the top of the list.  When the user clicks on the first or second item in the list, I would expect the selected index text to update accordingly.

Questions:

1. Am I implementing the navigation bar structure correctly with the layout and right navigation bar?
2. How can I make it work?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

This post is a bit old, but I thought I would share my experience just in case someone else comes across this. I fought the exact same issue for 2 days and finally got it working.

For me, it seemed to come down to two things. First, I changed:

```
export class NavMenu extends React.Component<NavMenuProps, null> {
```

and took off the "export" keyword:

```
class NavMenu extends React.Component<NavMenuProps, null> {
```

I'm guessing that with the export keyword in place, when you "import NavMenu" in another component, it's grabbing the actual NavMenu class, and not the one wrapped in Redux's Connect object.

Also, in the Layout.tsx file where I had the NavMenu in the markup, I apparently had the import statement wrong. I changed it to:

```
import NavMenu from './NavMenu';
```

All of this now works for me.
Sorry if my answer is a little confusing or inaccurate. I'm very new to React, and not much of a javascript expert either, so please don't flame me...